# List(with out scroll) inside a RecyclerView row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want a list inside a recycler view, I don't want nested scroll, what is the best approach for this?

What I am considering now is that dynamically add the inner list rows.
If that is the case, let the adapter hold the whole data for the inner list. The number of list rows in each row of the recycler view row is not fixed.

Please voice your opinions with pros and cons.

NB:- I dont have any code to post since I am working on this.

Comment: why don't use only a RecyclerView?

Comment: The number of list rows inside the Recyclerview row is not fixed.

Comment: i don't understand, forgive me, can you describe your problem more accurately? you have a recyclerview and in that recyclerview you want to put a set of vertical item that take the whole width, right? i'm losing some requirements?

Comment: for vertical items i mean like a listview or a vertical linearlayout

Comment: @firegloves There is a recycler view A, inside each row of A, there are lists, let each individual list be B, B can have any number of rows(varies across the row of list A)

Comment: You can use expandable listview

Comment: @WISHY I want to use Recyclerview.

Comment: for me having some listview inside a recyclerview will result in a performance issue. my suggestion is to have a more complex logic into RecyclerView's adapter but keep only a recycling object at a time

Comment: @firegloves I don't insist on having a list view really.
More over I want to do this in Kotlin.

Comment: i never used Kotlin, sorry :)

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat you can have TableLayout in each row but that will be heavy on the memory

Comment: @WISHY I am considering using this...
https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

But again converting this to Kotlin will be a challenge.

Comment: you can also have a look at this https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android?utm_source=drbl&utm_medium=special&utm_campaign=2121350-Delivery-Card

Comment: @WISHY Nice library, but I dont want the folding effect.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat I guess than the library you shared can work out for you

Comment: Yes, But I thought doing it in Kotlin. The library is originally in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Inside List View you need to Disable scrolling.

i.e listview.setNestedScrollingEnable(false);